# Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I don't see an error in my code should it work could someone tell me how to fix it?
thanks in advance :) any help is welcome

```
public class ListPatrimony extends AppCompatActivity {

 
  long money = 1;
```

---

```
public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child ("money").getValue(Long.class) >= 7) <- line error
                        { dataSnapshot.child ("money").getRef().setValue((money));
```

---

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertLong(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:384)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:295)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:214)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:203)
            at com.gangster.ui.activities.ListPatrimony$2$1.onDataChange(ListPatrimony.java:87)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you saved `money` into `String` while saving. So, can you change:

```
if (dataSnapshot.child ("money").getValue(Long.class) >= 7)
```

To

```
if (dataSnapshot.child ("money").getValue().toLong() >= 7)
```